# InDesign: Trying to target a group with script label...no dice

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I'm using InDesign CS6.

I have a table nested inside a group. The group is labeled "slug" using InDesign's script labels. I'm trying to insert information into the cells of that table.

I've gotten it to work without using labels if I target "group 1", but this doesn't work if there are any other groups in the layout (obviously not ok).

Here's my code. Note my failed attempt at targeting the group on line 7. Any ideas?

```
    tell application "Adobe InDesign CS6"
            set myDoc to active document
            set colorMode to blending space of transparency preferences of myDoc
            set docBleed to document bleed top offset of document preferences of myDoc
            set docWidth to page width of document preferences of myDoc
            set docHeight to page height of document preferences of myDoc

            set slugGroup to (group whose label is "slug")
            tell table 1 of text frame 1 of slugGroup of myDoc
                set contents of cell 1 of row 2 to colorMode
                set contents of cell 2 of row 1 to docWidth & " x " & docHeight
                set contents of cell 2 of row 2 to docBleed
            end tell
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I needed to target the FIRST group.

```
tell myDoc
    tell table 1 of text frame 1 of (first group whose label is "slug")
```